# Moving to the UK as a German, but keeping the German residency. Is this a bad idea?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, taxes, residency

I am a German and I will soon move to the UK to work there.

Because my partner is still living in Germany, and I will visit regularly, I plan to keep my residency (Hauptwohnsitz) registered in Germany. This seems to be possible since the UK is no longer part of the EU, am I right?

> **Question:** Is this a bad idea for any reason? For example, does Germany expect me to pay, e.g. social insurance contributions or a German health insurance, just because I have residency here?

I see various advantages of this approach: I have multiple insurances and some bank accounts that require (or at least prefer) that I have my primary residency in Germany.
Also, if I keep my current address, I will not have to deal with telling everyone (e.g. my insurances) that my address has changed, and so my mail will find its way to me.

Comment: This doesn't concern the EU at all. I come from an EU country that doesn't have a concept akin to the *Hauptwohnsitz* and tend to look at this in a very different way. You may or may not be able to get away with lying to the German authorities about it but either way, the way you describe it you would not actually reside in Germany (as a matter of fact). Consequently, you would be breaking the conditions of your insurance policy and may end up being denied payment whenever you try to make a claim against it.

Comment: Banking is probably somewhat less iffy, if and when the bank notices something is wrong they will ask you to close the account but you would not forfeit anything and can always deal with it at that time.

Comment: @Relaxed I do not plan to *lie* to anyone (I plan to be in either country approximately 50% of my time). If anything about my plan is illegal, this would be relevant information for me! Is there anything illegal happening from the perspective of one of the countries? I already called most of my insurances/banks and informed them about this plan, and they seemed to be fine with it.

Comment: Forget about the registration for one minute. Are you or are you not residing in Germany? Under what definition? Using words like "move to the UK to work there" and "visit regularly" suggest to me that you would reside in the UK and not in Germany. This creates an obligation to report that fact to the German authorities. On the other hand, if you do live in Germany then yes, you can remain registered there and you would in principle be *unbeschränkt steuerpflichtig* (buy we have to look at the tax treaty between the UK and Germany as well).

Comment: What I was trying to say is that registration should reflect your material situation. I have friends who got away with it for years but in principle, you don't get to create some half-residency without actualy residing there by omitting to notify the municipality. Incidentally, the bank might not even care about you not having your *Hauptwohnsitz* in Germany.

Comment: Incidentally, I wouldn't trust what some customer service rep told you on the phone. Whenever you try to get money from your insurer, you will have to deal with another department which will only care about their interpretation of the rules and what you can prove in writing (I had an issue like that around the date a car was exported from the Netherlands).

Comment: @Relaxed Hm. Since I do plan to be at both places for approximately the same amount of time, it is hard for me to say "where I am primarily residing" without a proper definition of that term. If I have to say something, I would tend to state it as you did, that I "reside in the UK and not in Germany". How am I going to report this to the German authorities and what are the consequences? I had the impression that I report this by "unregistering my residency" (excuse my lack of technical jargon).

Comment: Since your partner is still living at that residence and the fact that you will be regularly returning there is the defining factor that can it remain your main residence **in** Germany. As long as your partner can inform you swiftly that an official letter for you has arrived, so that you can react to it in a timly manner is the main criteria that must be fullfilled. If you are not sure, you can simply ask the registry office if it is ok.